# Processmaker 4 Community: How to install missing packages?

Tags: processmaker

I got a Bitnami image of Processmaker4 v4.1.20 Community.
I'm missing some features that were once included in Processmaker 3 Community like sending emails or a MySQL connector. The documentation says the "email package" has to be installed for sending emails and the "data connector package" for database connectivity. These packages are not installed.

Where can I get these packages and how are these installed? Or are these packages only available in commercial versions?

Answer (score 1):

Just to add something to the answer.  If you are using the Community Edition, this is easy to solve.  Just use a script task to send emails or connect to a a database.  But yes, we make easier in the Cloud version by already packaging these as pre-packaged connectors.

Not a blocker.

Comment: Is it possible though to develop open source ProcessMaker packages?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like those packages are behind the paywall.

As noted in [the release notes for ProcessMaker 4.1.16](https://processmaker.gitbook.io/processmaker-release-notes/processmaker-4.1-release-notes/non-core-package-versions), these are non-open-source packages.